# Amadeus api returning error

Tags: php, api, url, curl, amadeus

i am using there's api of hotel system and when i process there url 
(even in there site there own ) they return an error !

i genereted the url via theres url generator in the web site and i dont know why its giving me EOF ?

{
  "fault": {
    "faultstring": "Unexpected EOF at target",
    "detail": {
      "errorcode": "messaging.adaptors.http.flow.UnexpectedEOFAtTarget"
    }
  }
}

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are currently experiencing some network configuration issues.

Answer (score 1):

Amadeuse fixed the issue ! right now working  not code error